# the convergence of $f_n(x)=x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I had a weird question. Here is the description:

Let $\mu$ be the Borel Measure on ${\mathbf R}$ defined as $\mu(A)=m(A\cap[0,1])$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on ${\mathbf R}$, $A$ is the Borel set on ${\mathbf R}$. Then let $\delta_1$ be the Dirac measure on $x=1$, and $v=\mu+\delta_1$

Define $f_n\colon{\mathbf R}\to {\mathbf R}$ as $f_n(x)=x^n$, $n=1,2,...$

1. Prove that $f_n\to f$ a.e. on ${\mathbf R}$, where $f$ is a $v$-integrable function, and please show the specific form of $f$.
2. Calculate the limit :$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_n(x)\,\textrm{d}v.$$

Actually I was stucked by the negative part of $f_n(x)$,it's easy to solve the positive part,but when $x<0$,the convergence depends on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Which part gives you trouble, exactly? What have you done?

Comment: @tomasz added my confusion

Answer (score 0):

The negative part should not bother you, since the definition of the measure $\mu$ restricts you to the interval $[0,1]$. To be a bit more precise in explanation here, think back to the definition of $L^p$ spaces, where you identified functions which are equal-a.e. The same can be done here: Two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ are equal-a.e. if they have the same value in $x=1$ and are $m$-equal-a.e. (in the Lebesgue sense) on the interval $[0,1)$.

Thus to answer $(1)$ consider the function $f = 1_{\{1\}}$. $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ and therefore a.e., since on $[0,1]$ there is no point where $f_n \not\rightarrow f$ and the $\nu$-measure of all the other points is $0$. Clearly $f$ is $\nu$-integrable with value $1$.

To answer $(2)$ you just have to calculate the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]$ which is $1$. (If you want this more precise, tell me please.)

Comment: I know the measure $\mu$ is restricted to [0,1],but will it restrict the convergence to [0,1],why should we ignore the other parts like (1,+$\infty)$? I am still confused.Please be more precise,thanks a lot

Comment: @user415071 Konstantin is precise. If your measure is restricted to $[0,1]$, you **have to** ignore everything outside, i.e. $(-\infty,0)$ **and** $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @user415071 I tried to be a bit more detailed in explanation. I hope its clear(er) now :)

Comment: @Konstantin OK,that's it.I know why we ignore the other parts,since the definition of a.e. convergence is that the "disconvergence" area has measure 0,so actually the other parts are the "disconvergence" areas but they have v-measure 0,so under the v measure,it stands.Am I right?

Comment: @user415071 Yes, you are right :)